# How I can display data from two tables in dataset separately to crystal report?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

```
 datasetForReceiptObj.genralTable.Clear();
        datasetForReceiptObj.subjectTable.Clear();
        datasetForReceiptObj.genralTable.AddgenralTableRow(receiptNo, studentName, category, studentBranch);
        for (int i = 0; i < subject.Count; i++)
        {
            datasetForReceiptObj.subjectTable.AddsubjectTableRow(subject[i], amountRec[i]);
        }
        crystalReportForReceiptObj.SetDataSource(datasetForReceiptObj);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReportForReceiptObj;
```

Note:
    genralTable contains one row

```
    i.e.    111 abc degree cse

subjectTable contains two rows 

    i.e.     Java 2000
             C#   2000
```

Report display like :

```
   111 abc degree cse Java 2000
   111 abc degree cse   C# 2000
```

i.e. repeat the genralTable contents, i want no repetation of genralTable contents

like

```
         111 abc degree cse Java 2000
                            C#   2000
```

How I can display such output ?

Comment: How are you querying the data currently..? you will need to use one dataset and do a `JOIN` is what it sounds like to me..

Comment: i create manually two tables in dataset, and runtime that two tables are filled, (genralTable filled by one row, and subject tables fill by two rows)

Comment: U can add sub report ....and in sub report you can assign the record of second table.